# Discount mathematical operation with MySQL and PHP - Can't get result

Tags: php, mysql, database, math

I have this query for getting out the total amount of check after discount:
Please note that i have to multiply the quantity with price first

```
SELECT SUM(pino_order_item.ord_item_quan * pino_menu_item.menu_item_price) * (1 - pino_table_order.order_discount)
FROM pino_order_item join pino_menu_item join pino_table_order
WHERE ord_order_id = %s AND menu_item_id = ord_item_mid
```

I'm trying to echo this on my page with PHP like:

> echo number_format($row_get_total['SUM(ord_item_quan * menu_item_price) * (1 - order_discount)'],2);

It's not working at all .. it's giving me totally wrong numbers.

Please help me identify my coding problem and kindly note that all what i want is to multiply the quantity of order item with the price then calculate the discount entered as percentage number (20) or (30) for example and get 2 results (one before discount and one after discount)

Thank you in advance ....

Comment: What are your numbers, what result do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: @deceze .. For example I have (Quantity = 2) (Price = 10.00) (Discount = 0) .... Result -1,900.00  ...... I don't know if this code is right or wrong actually !!??

Comment: If the order_discount is 20 or 30 you need to make it a fraction (ie divide by 100) before subtracting it from 1

Comment: @xd6_ .. My problem is i don't know a lot about math and I don't know how I code math like this what you mentioned .. If you can please mention the all code for it will be great .. thanks

Comment: Do you have a discount per item or just one discount for the whole check?  The way you did your query you are calculating the sum of the check and then subtracting a discount.

Comment: How do the tables relate to each other. (Your naming policy is poor)

Comment: @ForguesR .. No .. I have discount for every check and sometimes don't have to the value 0 .. If i have the value to be 20 or 30 as percentage

Comment: @Strawberry .. It's not about the tables relations .. it's working fine for other queries .. maybe the technique is poor and thanks for your attention to me .. I will work on it

Comment: Oh, it's about the relations all right. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: @Strawberry .. Ok thanks ,, I will try to check and make some modifications . Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'm not seeing any group by keyword in the query, if you're trying to get the order total, you will need to group by the order_id.
- You said the discount value is stored as integers like 20 or 30. Subtracting that from 1 would give you unexpected values like -19 or -29 respectively. Which is probably the cause of the weird number you're complaining about.

Correct SQL should say something like this:

`SELECT SUM( tblItems.price ) * ( 1 - ( tblOrders.discount / 100 ) ) AS totalCheck FROM tblItems JOIN tblOrders USING order_id WHERE tblItems.order_id GROUP BY order_id`

Then something like this to echo the result:

`echo $row[ 'totalCheck' ]`